# Deleting duplicates with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey so I have one set of data with the structure:

```
id     product_number      product_type
1      1001                car
2      1002                house
```

But the data has some duplicates where:

```
id     product_number      product_type
1      1001                car
2      1001                house
```

I need to delete the duplicates but only the value which is = house.

In my mind the query should be like:

```
DELETE *
FROM table
WHERE product_number is duplicate AND product_type = house
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicated product_number and/or id?

Comment: Hi yes updated question, duplicates of product_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do what you want with a `join`:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         (select product, count(*) as cnt
          from table
          group by product
         ) tt
         on tt.product = t.product
    where tt.cnt > 1 and t.product_type = 'house';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE *
FROM table
WHERE id not in 
 (select max(id) from table  
       group by product_number)
```

AND product_type = house

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UPDATE query with a join like this:

```
delete t1.*
from
  t t1 INNER JOIN t t2
  ON t1.product_number = t2.product_number
     AND t1.product_type='house' AND (
       t2.product_type<>'house'
       OR t1.id>t2.id
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple methods:

**1.**
You can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table WHERE product_type = house)
```

**2.**
You can alter your table and change your product number column to add an index to it

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE jobs
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (product_number);
```

So the duplicated row with the same product number will be dropped automatically, and for more [see this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

**3.**
You can try this query to:

```
DELETE n1 FROM table_product p1, table_product p2 WHERE p1.product_number = p2.product_number AND p1.product_type= house
```